# Mysterious data type conversion to another data type error

Tags: c#, sql, .net, type-conversion

I have a web project working perfecly on my web server and on my local machine.

I sign up on another server provider because I need to migrate my application to a better place, and when I run my application I am receiving this error message:

`the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`

But I don't receive this error  locally nor on the other server, so I thought it would be some SQL configuration, sadly this error just occur on the code, when I run query on the database, it works perfectly. So I don't really know what to do at all!

I think its got to be the C# .net configuration but I have no clue where to start.

Since the application is working on everywhere else and for longtime, I've discarded the possibility of coding problem.

By the way, the error only occur when the code executes the query on the line: `sqlDa.Fill(dt);`

************************* UPDATED **********************

My web.config file which sets the culture of the application is the same as on the other servers as well. This server is located in another country so the culture is the problem.

Is there anywhere else I need to change the culture for the server?  or/and how can I see the culture of my sql data base?

Comment: The first thing I would look at is region settings.  In the US, `2012-03-21` is valid but it would fail in the EU since there is no month 21.

Comment: This can sometimes suggest a type mismatch between how SQL parameters are declared in the code and on a stored procedure.

Comment: There are no mysteries in computing. They are only perceived that way.

Comment: @JNK I've never heard of `YYYY-DD-MM` format; it's only the formats with the year last that vary (`21/3/2012` vs. `3/21/2012`).  (As an aside, I read at least two articles about the "terrorist attacks of November 9th" when I was living in Europe.)

Comment: Re Updated: Don't 'fix' the server, fix your code. And it's about the SQL server, not the Web server. Your hoster may not like/allow you to change the settings.

Comment: @phoog [It's still accepted in SQL Server](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=290971)

Comment: @JNK wow, thanks for the link, I never knew that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well guys, for everyone that helped me thx a lot..

I solved my problem, and I doubt someone will have the same problem as mine, but anyway, here is what i did to fix it:

You'll Need to have full access to the server, else you would have to use the CONVERT() function on every query, and that would be too much work.

So what I did was to change the default langue of my user on the sql server, and that solved my problem 100%

Ps: Never store a DateTime value on another data type. With that in mind, you will not have the same problem as mine!

Answer (score 2):

> the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type

Is culture dependent. All it takes is for the other server to run under a different locale.

You should review your (C# / SQL) code to see where this happens and take control of the conversion.
Best idea would be to eliminate it altogether. A string is not a Date.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is related with the locale of the server; or the locale of the SQL machine; or basicly it is because they do not match.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be converting the string into a date is being affected by the server being in a different locale?  You shouldn't be storing dates as strings, you are just asking for trouble.

How are you doing the conversion in the code?  What locale are your dates stored in in the db?  Are you specifying the local to use when doing the conversion to a date?

Answer (score 1):

The error message comes from the database, so it's likely that you are sending a string value to the database that it would need to convert to a datetime value. The conversion fails because the string contains a different date format from what the database expects.

You should use parameterised queries so that you send the value as a datetime value, and let the database driver worry about how it is sent to the database.

Comment: What i don't get is if  I execute the query on the database, I receive no erro and it works as it should.

Comment: @ShadowG: There may be a difference in the culture settings when you connect to the database from your code, and when you connect to it using the management software.

Comment: hey @Guffa for some reason when i logged on the data base using the windows credentials, everything works fine, that's why I wasn't getting no erros before.(wierd) anyway, this is the line that gives me the error:  `AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(D.Value AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) < 21` sadly I wasn't the one that created the data base structure, so the data is sotred as varchar and there is no way to convert it to datetime, since it stores lots of type of data :(

Comment: @ShadowG: Oh, that's nasty. ;) You can use the `convert` function to specify the date format, for example: `convert(datetime, D.Value, 120)`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for different date formats.

Comment: since i have access to everything on the server, I am trying to change the SQL server  default language, which is going to be a lot faster, because there are so many queries to alter. lol sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it's a locale/culture issue. You are probably passing a date in the where clause: `SELECT ... WHERE RecordDate>=<your date>`

When passing dates to the database, always format them with the yyyy-MM-dd format. The database will understand it regardless of its settings.